# Question on proof of $gcd(a,b)$ is the smallest positive linear combination

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I was reading the proof provided by CLRS and it said something along the lines (I will paraphrase):

let $LC_{a,b} = \{ ax + by : x,y \in \mathbb{Z}, ax+by >0 \}$.
let $s = min(LC_{a,b})$
consider $a \pmod s$:
$$a \pmod s = a -qp = a - q(ax + by) = a(1 -qx) + b(-qy)$$
Thus, $a \pmod s \in LC_{a,b}$ and we know $ 0\leq a \pmod s < s$.

The next step is the one that I don't understand from the proof. It says:

> we have that $a \pmod s = 0$ because $s$ is the smallest positive such
>   linear combination.

Basically, I don't understand how that justifies that $a \pmod s$ is zero.

This is what I thought. We know that a \pmod s (because its the remainder after dividing out by $s$) AND we also know that $a \pmod s \in LC_{a,b}$ because of the algebra I provided above. Therefore, it seems that $a \pmod s$ is a linear combination of a and b but its also smaller than the smallest linear combination by inequality $a \pmod s$. This seems like nonsense or a contradiction, which is putting me off. Anyone know why I am wrong?

---

I will provide a screenshot of the original proof:

[image]

I basically don't understand:

> But, since $0 \leq a \pmod s < s$, we have that $a mod s = 0$, because $s$ is the smallest positive such linear combination.

for the reasons I already explained above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $0\le a\bmod s<s$, there are two possible cases:

- $a\bmod s=0$;
- $0<a\bmod s<s$.

However the second case (together with things you have proved already) says that $a\bmod s$ is a **positive linear combination** of $a$ and $b$ which is **less than the smallest** positive linear combination of $a$ and $b$.  This is impossible, so only the first case remains.

Comment: I see, so basically $a \pmod s \not \in LC_{a,b}$.

Comment: last question, why do we need that $s > 0$ in the 2nd to last line of the proof?

Comment: @CharlieParker Because it's not true for $s=0$: $n\mid 0$ for any $n$. If $m\mid n$ with $m,n>0$, then we have $mx=n$ for some $x\in\Bbb Z$, and since $m,n$ are positive so is $x$, whence $x\ge1$ and $m\le n$.

Comment: Re your first comment, not really, on the contrary, $a\bmod s$ **is** an element of $LC_{a,b}$, and it's smaller than the smallest element.  This is impossible.  Re your second comment, I can't see which bit of the proof you are referring to.

Comment: why do we need $s>0$ right at the end of the CLRS proof. If you see how I defined $LC_{a,b}$, I disallowed zero to be in the set. if $a \pmod s = 0$ as you correctly convinced me, then it can't be in $LC_{a,b}$ the way I defined it.

Comment: @CharlieParker Right, that's the contradiction. $a\bmod s$ *is* a linear combination of $a,b$; so the only thing preventing it from being in your set is if it is not positive. If it were positive, then contradiction - so it must be $0$.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read the definition of $LC_{a,b}$ carefully.  You have proved that $a\bmod s$ is in $LC_{a,b}$, and also that it's not (because it's zero), which is a contradiction.

Comment: The $s>0$ in the third last line of the screen shot is showing that $\gcd(a,b)\le s$.  Note that this would not be true if $s$ were $0$ or negative, that's why they need to make the point that $s>0$.

Comment: I know the fact that if its $s = 0$ then the proof doesn't work. But that subtle point is not clear to me because I don't know why thats an issue. Btw, thnx for ur help so far.